# How to fix Bootstrap sub drop-down menu to the left side when mouse hover on it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a menu with a dropdown like this.

```
<li class="nav-item flyout">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle nav_sp_clr {{#ifpage 'quicklink'}}active{{/ifpage}}">Quick Links</a>
          <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked ">

              <li class="flyout-alt my-flyout-alt nav-sub-menu">
                    <a href="jobs.html" target="_blank" >Jobs</a>
              </li>

              <li class="flyout-alt my-flyout-alt nav-sub-menu  ">
                    <a href="uploads/MBA-Workshop.pdf" download="">NIRF</a>
                      <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked ">
                        <li><a href=#>ENGINEERING</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>MANAGEMENT</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>OVERALL</a></l]i>
                      </ul>
             </li>    
          </ul>
</li>
```

Here's my CSS classes code

```
.flyout, .flyout-alt{
          position:relative;
       }
      .flyout-content{
          position:absolute;
          top:100%;
          left:-99999px;
       }
.flyout:hover > .flyout-content{
    left:0;
}

.flyout-alt > .flyout-content{
    top:0;
    left:-99999px;
}
.flyout-alt:hover > .flyout-content{
    top:0;
    left:100%;
}
.flyout-content li a{
           color: #193e5a;
           display: block;
            background: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
 }

.flyout-content li a:hover{
    background-color: #c3c3c3;
  }
.flyout-content li:hover{
          background-color: #c3c3c3;
 }
 .my-flyout-alt{
      color: #193e5a;    
 }
.nav-sub-menu{
         width: 135px;
 }
 .nav-sub-menu li:hover{
       width: 135px;
  }
   .my-flyout-alt ul{
           text-align: center;
            background: #fff;
   }
```

This is my whole code. Please try to understand and answer my question. What I want is when I hover on the NIRF link the submenu has to come on the left side, not on the right side.

I tried left CSS property but it's not working as expecting my output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions

1. Add this to your css

```
 .my-flyout-alt:hover > .flyout-content{
        top: 20px ;
        left: -10% ;
 }
```

OR

2. Change

```
.flyout-alt:hover > .flyout-content
```

to

```
.flyout-alt:hover > .flyout-content{
    top:20px;
    left:-10%;
}
```

and alter the *left* percentage as per your need.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, brother. Quick solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.flyout, .flyout-alt{
          position:relative;
       }
.flyout-content{
          position:absolute;
          top:100%;
          left:-99999px;
       }
.staked li{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.staked{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
.flyout:hover > .flyout-content{
    left:0;
}

.flyout-alt > .flyout-content{
    top:0;
    left:-99999px;
}
.flyout-alt:hover > .flyout-content{
    top: 100%;
    left:0;
}
.flyout-content li a{
           color: #193e5a;
           display: block;
            background: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
 }

.flyout-content li a:hover{
    background-color: #c3c3c3;
  }
.flyout-content li:hover{
          background-color: #c3c3c3;
 }
 .my-flyout-alt{
      color: #193e5a;    
 }
.nav-sub-menu{
         width: 135px;
 }
 .nav-sub-menu li{
  width: 135px;
 }
 .nav-sub-menu li:hover{
       width: 100%;
  }
   .my-flyout-alt ul{
           text-align: center;
            background: #fff;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li class="nav-item flyout">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle nav_sp_clr {{#ifpage 'quicklink'}}active{{/ifpage}}">Quick Links</a>
          <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked ">

              <li class="flyout-alt my-flyout-alt nav-sub-menu">
                    <a href="jobs.html" target="_blank" >Jobs</a>
              </li>

              <li class="flyout-alt my-flyout-alt nav-sub-menu  ">
                    <a href="uploads/MBA-Workshop.pdf" download="">NIRF</a>
                      <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked ">
                        <li><a href=#>ENGINEERING</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>MANAGEMENT</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>OVERALL</a></li>
                      </ul>
             </li>    
          </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: This is not my current solution but your answer will help in the future to me. Thanks to you too.